# How to seperate "container" resource limit in dev/production phase?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I have two development phases, `dev` and `prod`. and it could be distinguished as `.Values.profile`

In dev, the below resource limit is enough.

```
cpu: 4
memory: 4Gi
ephemeral-storage: 4Gi
```

However, I have to increase it as below while using `prod` phase.

```
cpu: 8
memory: 16Gi
ephemeral-storage: 16Gi
```

I tried to write my `deployment.yaml` as follows, and it works.

```
name : my-app
...      
resources:
    limits:
    {{ if (eq .Values.profile "dev")}}
    cpu: 4
    memory: 4Gi
    ephemeral-storage: 4Gi
    {{ end }}
    {{ if (eq .Values.profile "prod")}}
    cpu: 8
    memory: 16Gi
    ephemeral-storage: 16Gi
    {{end}}
```

However, I wondered what is the best practice to separate container resources between two phases.

Thank you!

Comment: I'd provide a set of resource constraints directly in the Helm-specific `values.yaml` file, using a `helm install -f` option to provide a different set of values per environment, but that's not the only way to do it.

Comment: I also advice @DavidMaze 's solution. Did you try it? Did it work for you?

Comment: I used `values.yaml` as @DavidMaze 's solution, and it works! @kkopczak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a separate values.yaml file for each environment.
E.g. values_dev.yaml , values_prod.yaml.
Put the environment specific values in the corresponding yamls.
Based on the environment on which the deployment is being done, pass the corresponding values.yaml file as argument helm install command.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not bound to helm you can also check out

1. kustomize

With kustomize you have the possibility to create overlays that overwrite certain values in a deployment. For example you would have a deployment yaml that contains the dev resources and an overlay for prod that defines different values. It's part of kubectl so you don't need extra tools. [Kustomize website](https://kustomize.io/)

2. Terraform

With Terraform you can create modules that describe your deployment containing variables, that serve as placeholder. Depending on the environment you can inject different values into that variables and by this configure your deployment. It's more similar to helm but much more readable. [Terraform and Kubernetes](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/kubernetes/latest/docs)

In general it's always the same principal, independent of the tool. You create a Kubernetes resource and set the values for your environment, so you reduce duplication and simplify the setup process.